# Need specific kind of "Poll Voting" for Wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-recommendation

I'm designing a website for a client. I don't really know how I got landed with all the backend structure code, but I did. I'm not an awful programmer, but I need something solid to work off, I can't just code my own program.

I need a plugin or some code that will automatically place a poll with **three** options to each post. Preferably, the OUTCOME of the poll would be displayed with the excerpt, then the actual poll would be on the full post page. That would be ideal, but I'll take what I can get. I just need a poll that will be attached to each post and work inline. IE: Not something I have to slap on a sidebar. Something that I can add to the index.php file with my loop, and also the single.php file would be excellent. However this might get tricky as the poll results would have to be dynamic to each post. I would also be okay with having to add a shortcode to each post (as there are plug-ins which can add shortcodes to posts by default without anyone being able to see them) but that seems sort of hack and slash to me.

Thanks for any help on this. Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: the wp-polls plugin has a [poll] shortcode which you can use to insert polls in posts. another way would be to use custom fields

Comment: WP-Polls Certainly comes very close to what I need. However, I need a poll that will be dynamic to each post. Meaning, technically, a different poll (with the same options..) for each post. WP-Polls results don't change depending on the post you're looking at, which is what I would need. Now, if there was a way for me to somehow add a new poll every time someone posts, or if there's a setting somewhere to change the poll results depending on the post it appears in, it would be perfect.

Comment: Is this poll something like "How would you rate this post? Bad/Meh/Very Good" ?

Comment: Yes, I think that would fit the general idea very well.

Comment: BTW, I'm currently trying out the "Vote it Up" plug in, but this plug in only supports 2 options, and I'm not the worlds best programmer, as I've said (I'm still taking PHP classes) so I'm not sure how to add a 3rd. But if I could, it'd be close to perfect.

Comment: you need a "3-way" voting plugin. I'm not aware of such a plugin but you can build one yourself based on this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cdnvote

Comment: Thanks, I am going to go give that a try now. I appreciate the help very much!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is better but it might be worth a look http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/polldaddy/

Comment: I ended up using "emo vote" which is way nicer and mature than it sounds.

Comment: @Lynne you should post "emo vote" as a separate answer, since it is the one you ended up using.