# WP 3-way voting system: On to something! Please help!

Tags: plugin-development, functions

Okay I posted a question yesterday, that can be found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6898/need-specific-kind-of-poll-voting-for-wordpress).

I've found some code on the wonderful internet that I think is really the ticket for me, but I don't know how to develop into what I really need. Here is the breakdown -

I need three separate vote links. 
I need to change the word "Vote" on each to something else. IE: Good/Meh/Bad. (I think I can figure this one out)

I'm hoping there is a simple and easy way to slap another two vote links into this code, because the code itself is really simple and easy. Just beg pardon my lack of PHP/Jquery knowledge.

Header code:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ) ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".vote a").click(
function() {
var some = jQuery(this);
var thepost = jQuery(this).attr("post");
var theuser = jQuery(this).attr("user");
jQuery.post("<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/vote.php", {user: theuser, post: thepost}, 
function(data) {
var votebox = ".vote"+thepost+" span";
jQuery(votebox).text(data);
jQuery(some).replaceWith('<span class="voted">Voted</span>');
});
});
}); 
</script>
```

vote.php file:

```
<?php
$file = dirname(__FILE__);
$file = substr($file, 0, stripos($file, "wp-content") );

require( $file . "/wp-load.php");

$currentvotes = get_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'votes', true);
$currentvotes = $currentvotes + 1;

$voters = get_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'thevoters', true);
if(!$voters) $voters = $_POST['user']; else $voters = $voters.",".$_POST['user'];

update_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'votes', $currentvotes);
update_post_meta($_POST['post'], 'thevoters', $voters);

echo $currentvotes;
?>
```

Functions.php reference:

```
function voting($id) {
global $user_ID;
$currentvotes = get_post_meta($id, 'votes', true);
$voters = get_post_meta($id, 'thevoters', true);
$voters = explode(",", $voters);
foreach($voters as $voter) {
 if($voter == $user_ID) $alreadyVoted = true;
}

if(!$currentvotes) $currentvotes = 0;
echo '<div class="vote vote'.$id.'"><span>'.$currentvotes.'</span>';
if($user_ID && !$alreadyVoted) echo '<br /><a post="'.$id.'" user="'.$user_ID.'">'.__("Vote").'</a>';
if($user_ID && $alreadyVoted) echo '<br /><span class="voted">'.__("Voted").'</span>';
echo '</div>';
if(!$user_ID) echo '<div class="signup"><p><a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-login.php?action=register">'.__('Register').'</a> '.__('to vote').'.</p></div>';
}
```

[Source has a demo.](http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/simple-voting-for-wordpress-with-php-and-jquery/#comment-22693)

Any and all help with this would be really, really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution. Append the ratings to the end of the post content:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'add_ratings_to_content', 4);

// remove ratings from excerpts
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', create_function('', 'remove_filter("the_content", "add_ratings_to_content", 6); return;'), 5);

function add_ratings_to_content($content){
  global $post;
  if(is_single()) $content .= the_ratings($post->ID);
  return $content;
}
```

Displays the current rating:

```
function get_current_rating($post_id){
  $votes = get_option("votes_{$post_id}");

  // handle your rating format here
  $output = '';
  if(isset($_COOKIE["rated_{$post_id}"])) $output .= "Your rating: ".esc_attr($_COOKIE["rated_{$post_id}"]);
  if(is_array($votes)):
    $output .= isset($votes['bad']) ? "{$votes['bad']} people think this sucks." : null;
    $output .= isset($votes['meh']) ? "{$votes['meh']} people said meh." : null;
    $output .= isset($votes['good']) ? "{$votes['good']} people think this post was good." : null;
  else:
    $output = "no votes yet";
  endif;
  return $output;
}
```

The ajax request. Use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to do a IP check for multiple votes because cookies can be deleted easily (and store the IP+post id somewhere, like a [transient](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API))

```
add_action('init', 'process_vote');
function process_vote() {
  if($_GET['vote']):
    $rating = esc_attr($_GET['vote']);
    $post_id =  esc_attr($_GET['post_id']);

    $already_voted = isset($_COOKIE["rated_{$post_id}"]) ? true : false;
    $current_rating = get_current_rating($post_id);

    if ($post_id && in_array($rating, array('bad', 'meh', 'good')) && !$already_voted):
      // update db
      $votes = get_option("votes_{$post_id}");
      $votes[$rating] = isset($votes[$rating]) ? ($votes[$rating]+1) : 1;
      update_option("votes_{$post_id}", $votes);

      setcookie("rated_{$post_id}", $rating, time() + (86400 * 30)); // 30 day cookie
      echo get_current_rating($post_id);
    else:
      echo "Already voted?";
    endif;

    die();
  endif;
}
```

the HTML for the ratings, simple stuff, no css:

```
function the_ratings($post_id = false, $disabled = false){
  $already_voted = isset($_COOKIE["rated_{$post_id}"]) ? true : false;

  ob_start(); ?>
  <?php if(!$already_voted && !$disabled): ?>
  <p>How would you rate this?</p>
  <ul class="vote-process">
    <li><a rel="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">bad</a></li>
    <li><a rel="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">meh</a></li>
    <li><a rel="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">good</a></li>
  </ul>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="vote-status">
    <?php echo get_current_rating($post_id); ?>
  </div>
 <?php
 return ob_get_clean();
}
```

The JavaScript, included in the page footer.

```
add_action("wp_footer", "ratings_js");
function ratings_js(){ ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $(".vote-process a").click(function () {

        var id = $(this).attr('rel');
        var post = $("#post-"+id);
        var link = $(this).html();

        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>",
          data: {
            post_id: id,
            vote: link
          },

          beforeSend: function() {
            post.find(".vote-status").html("Please wait...");
          },
          success: function(response){
            post.find(".vote-status").html(response);
            post.find(".vote-process").remove();
          }
        });
      });

    });
    /* ]]> */
  </script>
   <?php
}
```

Remove the votes_postid option when a post is deleted:

```
add_action('delete_post', 'remove_votes');
function remove_votes($post_id){
  delete_option("votes_{$post_id}");
  return $post_id;
}
```

I'd still recommend using CDNvote, because the code is very simple and flexible, and uses it's own database table...

Comment: Wow! and all called in functions.php too, easy to manipulate. Thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed, and it's easy for me to read, so I can edit it in some ways without going insane. I really appreciate your help, and the time you took to do this.

Comment: Hey, AA. I don't know if this notifies you if you get an update. I hate to e-mail you personally and I don't think this constitutes completely new post. I've been playing with CDNvote and I can see its potential, but really until I take my PHP/SQL class this semester, I'm just not able to work with the code very well. Thankfully I do have a javascript book, but I think it works a little differently inside wordpress. The code you gave me is great and I really have no complaints. I'm just wondering if there's a way for me to show the post data on exceprts. <?php get_current_rating($post_id) ?>..

Comment: ^^^ Doesn't work properly. It shows 'no votes yet' which makes me think that I'm doing something right, however it does not tie in to the vote count properly. Is there a way to do this or does that require a datastructure?

Comment: nevermind........ FYI - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/emo-vote/installation/